# Set focus on view inside ScrollView

Tags: android

I have long `scrollView`, and button on end, when I press `button` I want unfiled layout to get focus(bring back user up to the unfiled view).

I tried with `RequestFocus()`, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to scroll the scrollbar position.

```
  scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
```